# D3.js (v4) custom arc(path) generation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, path

```js
var data = ["4.11","4.11","4.11","4.11","4.11","4.11"];
    var radarCanvas = d3.select('#div_id')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width','780')
          .attr('height','600')
          .attr('class', 'graph');

    var r = 78;
    var p = Math.PI * 2;



    var drawCircleLvl1 = radarCanvas.append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(210,210)')
          .attr('fill', '#cdecfa');
    var drawCircleLvl2 = radarCanvas.append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(210,210)')
          .attr('fill', '#b1def2');
    var drawCircleLvl3 = radarCanvas.append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(210,210)')
          .attr('fill', '#93d3ed');
    var drawCircleLvl4 = radarCanvas.append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(210,210)')
          .attr('fill', '#70c8e6');
    var favAreaArc = radarCanvas.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(210,210)')
      .attr('fill', '#CC9FC2')
      .attr('opacity', '.7');
    var cardinal = radarCanvas.append('g');

   
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var section = data[i];

      var drawArcLvl1 = d3.svg.arc()
          .innerRadius(r)
          .outerRadius(r+30)          .startAngle(startAngle(i+1,data.length))
          .endAngle(endAngle(i+1,data.length));
          
        

      var drawArcLvl2 = d3.svg.arc()
          .innerRadius(r+30)
          .outerRadius(r+60)
          .startAngle(startAngle(i+1,data.length))
          .endAngle(endAngle(i+1,data.length));
        

      var drawArcLvl3 = d3.svg.arc()
          .innerRadius(r+60)
          .outerRadius(r+90)
          .startAngle(startAngle(i+1,data.length))
          .endAngle(endAngle(i+1,data.length));
         

      var drawArcLvl4 = d3.svg.arc()
          .innerRadius(r+90)
          .outerRadius(r+120)
          .startAngle(startAngle(i+1,data.length))
          .endAngle(endAngle(i+1,data.length));
          
       


    drawCircleLvl1.append('path')
        .attr('d', drawArcLvl1);
    drawCircleLvl2.append('path')
        .attr('d', drawArcLvl2);
    drawCircleLvl3.append('path')
        .attr('d', drawArcLvl3);
    drawCircleLvl4.append('path')
        .attr('d', drawArcLvl4);

    }
   



    function startAngle(k,n) {
      return ((k-1)*Math.PI*2)/n;
    }
    function endAngle(k,n) {
      return (k*Math.PI*2)/n;
    }

    function middlePointX(k,n) {
      return (210 + Math.sin((2*k-1)*((2*Math.PI)/(2*n)))*(r+175));
    }

    function middlePointY(k,n) {
      return (210 - Math.cos((2*k-1)*((2*Math.PI)/(2*n)))*(r+175));
    }

    function scoreCX(k,n) {
      return (210 + Math.sin((2*k-1)*((2*Math.PI)/(2*n)))*((r-30)+(section.allObserversAverageScore*30)));
    }

    function scoreCY(k,n) {
      return (210 - Math.cos((2*k-1)*((2*Math.PI)/(2*n)))*((r-30)+(section.allObserversAverageScore*30)));
    }

    var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    var bbox = svg.getBBox();

    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", (bbox.x-10)+" "+(bbox.y-10)+" "+(bbox.width+20)+" "+(bbox.height+20));
    svg.setAttribute("width", (bbox.width+20)  + "px");
    svg.setAttribute("height",(bbox.height+20) + "px");
```

```css
tAngle(...).endAngle(...).padAngle is not a function",
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div_id"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have managed to write some code to generate  arcs with d3.js using a dynamic set of data. Basically i divide the length of the circle in radians, and the generated arcs have the same length. I used 4 sets(levels) of arcs for each slice. Can someone give me an idea or point the direction which i should take to  generate custom path for each arc? As you can see, [example_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoNyZ.png) is my result,[example_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytlyx.png) is where i want to get. So i want to modify the paths of 1'st and 4'th level arcs(indicated as "1" and "2" in the image) and make them rounder. I tried to modify the border radius, but that doesn't help in this particularly situation.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that this is your first question on SO. If you don't share your code (be it v3 or v4, working or non-working) not only nobody will be able to help you, but also your question is off topic.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado for the feedback. I copy/pasted and edited the code, added some data to generate the arcs, for some reason it throws an error using padAngle, so the svg generated is not exactly as in example_1. I just need info about issue described in the topic title.

Comment: Have you looked at the `cornerRadius` function on `d3.arc`?

Comment: Yes, i have tried cornerRadius but this doesn’t resolve it. I need to modify just the bottom left and right arc corners radius of the first lvl arcs(“1”) and top left + right arc corners radius for the 4’th lvl(“2”) - see example_2.png.